# Wiring multiple Displays to Rasberry Pi

Tags: display

I want to connect multiple LCD (or LED) displays to one single Raspberry Pi module to show some text on each display separately.
(fps doesn't matter because there is a static text or numbers on the screen).

[image: Small LCD display]

Is it possible to connect multiple TFT Displays for a single Raspberry Pi board?
What is the maximum number of displayd I can connect to one single Raspberry Pi?

Comment: If you are not very much worried about FPS try displays that support i2c interfaces. This will allow you to connect multiple devices. To answer your question on SPI bus which comes onboard for display, they cannot support multiple devices. There are multiplexers available for Cameras however it will become more expensive compared to RPi and display

Answer (score 0):

If the display is I2C compatible there is a device sold for I2C expansion in the Arduino world, it is called a "TCA9548A I2C Multiplexer Module" It will work at 3.3 and 5 volts. It converts a single channel to 8 independent channels. You simply select the channel you want then communicate with the peripherals on that buss as though they were connected to the Pi. If you want something else simply select that channel. They are not that expensive and there are several configurations available from several vendors. With the SPI buss you connect them parallels and select with the CS\ pin.